# Javascript - Placing a constant on prototype

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

Let's say i have the following class:

```
function Base() {};
Base.prototype.Const = 0;
```

and a derived function:

```
function Derived() {};
```

The Derived function has access to this.Const .
Now my question is - I haven't seen any case where people define Consts on the prototype and i wonder why not? Is there any problem using this method?
(it seems like a good practice to me since the const in not global and contained within the class and it's not on the this)

I'm not necessarily talking about a constant - but a variable that all the derived classes might want to use... like ID or something else

Comment: Anybody can access it and modify it though.

Comment: Constants are typically static "class properties" on the constructor, because, y'know, every constant is static…

Comment: @Sandman what makes you think that people don't do this?

Comment: @elclanrs: Anybody can access and modify (nearly) anything in JS :-) Usually there's no reason to worry.

Comment: No worries, just pointing out that this is still global and not really "contained"

Comment: @shafeen i asked some people and not a single person did it like this.

Comment: @elclanrs - it is somewhat contained because it is not really on the global and every instance of the derived class can access the constant using "this"

Comment: @bergi - if you put in the constructor than you will get for every new instance of the class the constant all over again - which is wasteful

Comment: @Sandman: I said *on* the constructor, not *in* the constructor: `Base.Const = 0`.

Comment: @Bergi Your method is not as good - i will expain.
If i were to put Base.MY_SERVICE_ID = 0 for example, and i had in my derived class a function:
Derived.getIsServiceIdZero - i would have to compare the function to Base.MY_SERVICE_ID instead of just this.

This would mean that from every derived classes that i use i would always have to call Base.MY_Service_ID , instead of just this.
Therefore the this way has more benefit - i don't have to know the name of the base class

Comment: No, using `Base.MyServiceId` instead of `this.MyServiceId` has exactly the benefit that it is explicitly linked to the constant that the `Base` class specifies, and not to some possibly overwritten different one from `Derived`. Constants shouldn't be overwritable, right? And you wouldn't use any constants without knowing the base class anyway.

Comment: @Sandman Semantically using `this` to me reads as a property on an instance that I'm allowed/supposed to change, whereas if I've explicitly got to reference `Base`/some other object name then I'd be having second thoughts about modifying it.

Comment: @Bergi Let's say that i have a derived to the derived class (let's call it a grandson class) - it shouldn't know the Base class only the Derived class.
Let's say someone gave me the Derived class to inherit from, i have no idea who is the Base and i don't care. i just know that i have on the "this" the Variable.
By the way - would your answer be the same if it wasn't a const?

Comment: If you don't care, you don't care about that constant either, do you? Just call the `super` method who knows about the constant.

Comment: you are using it right. check the javascript definitive guide book http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch08_04.htm

Comment: @Darshan Thanks, this is the answer i've been looking for - can you post it as an answer to the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using it right according to the JavaScript definitive guide 
[Book](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch08_04.htm)